# Fermi level upto which Boltzmann approximation can be made

Tags: analog

Thou this is a solved excercise problem but I have a doubt.
Since 
$$ N_0=n_i* \exp{\left(\frac{E_{F_i}-E_F}{kT}\right)}\text,$$
 so for Boltzmann approximation to be valid we should take limiting condition as \$E_{F_i}-E_F=3kT\$ then why instead of this in this example \$E_F-E_a\$ have been assumed to be \$3kT\$.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoKQ5.jpg]

Comment: seriously, why do you assume it's OK to change the capitalization of formula symbols randomly? Makes it much harder to understand your problem, since one first has to guess what each letter means. You're not even consistent in your question! Next time, please be more diligent with formula symbols.

Comment: Sorry . I will take care of this from next time.

Answer (score 1):

Bolzmann's approximation means replacing the Fermi-Dirac distribution function by the simpler "exponential only" one (=no denominator needed) which is Bolzmann's statistical distribution function. This approximation is valid when the exponential in the Fermi-Dirac distribution function is large enough when compared to 1. Your book states that large enough is exp(3) or approximately 20.

Your first equation is from where this approximation is used to calculate the needed N doping concentration from the wanted new Fermi level.

The boron example applies it to the acceptor doping Na, because the holes also obey the same distribution law, but everything is mirrored relative to midgap.

The formula for the difference between the doped and intrinsic fermi levels = Eg/2 - (Ea-Ev) - (Ef - Ea) is a clever shuffle to insert the difference of the new fermi level and the new boron-introduced acceptor energy level.

Comment: Elegant answer, I could have used your help when I wrote [\$n_c \approx e^{-E_{bg}/k_B T}\$](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/20096/12102).